# PHP prevent opening div to be added to closing div

Tags: php, html

I'm adding a closing `</div>` in php but an opening div is automatically added to it.

My code:

```
<?php ...  ?>

</div>

<?php ... ?>
```

I'm adding `</div` to close a parent div. How can I prevent an opening div to be added to it?

Comment: Your Question is unclear. Please discride your problem

Comment: what program are you writing this HTML in ?

Comment: It is written in a .php file

Comment: You use some kind of WYSIWYG-Editor?

Comment: No WYSIWYG-Editor. It is a simple .php file in wordpress

Comment: Are you sure you've not just added a mismatching close tag and the _browser_ is trying to fix it?

Comment: In the code you posted, your closing div is outside the PHP block. Are you sure that the opening div is really getting created by your code? To avoid mistakes, consider placing the matching open/close divs outside the PHP blocks. If that is not possible, place both the open and close divs inside your PHP block so you can easily match them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers usually close tags if these are missing. If you just `echo "<pre>";` in the browser you will see `<pre></pre>`;

In your example, if the browser is adding an opening `<div>`, it is beacause you're not closing divs properly. Check all your closing tags, and then it will close the div that you want.

Comment: Yes turns out that I needed to add more closing divs. I thought it was a more complicated issue.